# Pass environment variable from preinstall script to postinstall of third party npm package

Tags: npm, pnpm, rush

I am trying to use a third party package whose postinstall script needs rust compiler to build rust code to create node native module. There is an opt-in environment flag supported by the package which lets people use pre-built binary rather than building it during install (and even needing the compiler).

I am trying to find a way to set this environment variable through a preinstall script in my project. But setting an env variable in script is scoped to that script and does not propagate to the postinstall phase of the third party package.

One way to set this environment variable is just by setting it in user profile or in the terminal manually. But there are huge number of developers working on the project and asking everyone to set it seems disruptive.

Is there a way to achieve this?

My project uses rush, which uses pnpm.